# How to apply :focus on multiple identical selectors?

Tags: html, css, input, bootstrap-4, focus

I'm trying to change the bottom border color when input type number is focused. In part I succeeded, but the css is not applied to all selectors. Here's the problem:

[image]

The left side (peso) is not focused, yet it has the same selector as Kg. Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/nLdrcv71/1/

```
input[type=number] {
    color: #666;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px !important;
    border-color: #dcdcdc !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    background: #fafafa00;
}

.input-group-text {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #ffffff00 !important;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc !important;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.form-control:focus,
.form-control:focus + span {
    color: #00a1ff;
    background-color: #fff0;
    border-color: #00a1ff !important;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px !important;
}

.input-group-text:focus {
    background:red !important;
}
```

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text">Peso</span>
  <input type="number" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-text">Kg</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Peso is not underlined because it precedes the focused input whereas the Kg is the immediate following sibling. Did you want all that group underlined when the input is focused?

Comment: That's right, I wanted the whole group to be underlined + the weight and kg text the same color as the border. I tried a bit with div and focus: within, I managed with the bottom border, but I can't color the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selector `.form-control:focus + span` only affects span that come after elements with the `.form-control` class. Instead of this, you can use `.input-group:focus-within span` which will apply your styling to children span when elements with the `.input-group` class are focused.

```css
.form-control:focus,
.input-group:focus-within span {
    color: #00a1ff;
    background-color: #fff0;
    ...
```

---

Edit: I have added the full markup to demonstrate that this solution does work.

```css
input[type=number] {
    color: #666;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px !important;
    border-color: #dcdcdc !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    background: #fafafa00;
}

.input-group-text {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #ffffff00 !important;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc !important;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.form-control:focus,
.input-group:focus-within span {
    color: #00a1ff;
    background-color: #fff0;
    border-color: #00a1ff !important;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px !important;
}

.input-group-text:focus {
    background:red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text">Peso</span>
  <input type="number" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-text">Kg</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur, I have added the full markup to demonstrate my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the order of the HTML elements so that "Peso" is after the `<input type="number">`, switch to using the [`~` CSS general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) to select all adjacent siblings, and use [CSS `order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to change the order of the flex children from your CSS.

```css
input[type=number] {
    color: #666;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px !important;
    border-color: #dcdcdc !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    background: #fafafa00;
}

.first-input {
    order: 1;
}

.second-input {
    order: 2;
}

.third-input {
    order: 3;
}

.input-group-text {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #ffffff00 !important;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc !important;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.form-control:focus,
.form-control:focus ~ span {
    color: #00a1ff;
    background-color: #fff0;
    border-color: #00a1ff !important;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px !important;
}

.input-group-text:focus {
    background:red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="number" class="second-input form-control">
  <span class="first-input input-group-text">Peso</span>
  <span class="third-input input-group-text">Kg</span>
</div>
```

> The **general sibling combinator** (`~`) separates two selectors and matches all iterations of the second element, that are following the first element (though not necessarily immediately), and are children of the same parent [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Element).

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

> The `order` [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) property sets the order to lay out an item in a flex or grid container. Items in a container are sorted by ascending `order` value and then by their source code order.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

---

My solution was inspired by Paco Coursey's blog post [CSS Previous Sibling Selector](https://paco.sh/blog/css-previous-sibling-selector).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the result I was looking for. A last question. Is it possible to eliminate the spin that makes the numbers rotate?

Comment: @EmanueleDaniele which spin are you referring to? The numbers do not rotate for me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have tried it and it works great. However I chose a different solution and ticked the check on @George Sun previous answer. I found it easier, although I slightly adapted the code to apply it to the div and span, so I avoided all first input orders. Thanks again.

As far as spins are concerned, I mean those buttons that appear when you focus to increase or decrease numbers without typing a number.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just toggle a .focused class on it whenever the input is focused or blurred.

Your css should look like this (just added a .focused after the other "+ span" thingy):

```css
.form-control:focus, .form-control:focus + span, .focused {
    color: #00a1ff;
    background-color: #fff0;
    border-color: #00a1ff !important;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px !important;
}
```

and you have to add this JavaScript code:

```js
let input = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0];
let firstSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("input-group-text")[0];

input.addEventListener("focus", addClass);
input.addEventListener("blur", removeClass);

function addClass() {
    firstSpan.classList.add("focused");
}

function removeClass() {
    firstSpan.classList.remove("focused");
}
```

Here's the working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/y1h8abnw/39/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried your solution, I believe it is the shortest and it incorporates less code. However, having hardly any knowledge with JS I didn't want to add any code that I might go back to tweaking and not understanding in the future. So I chose to stick with CSS only. Don't get me wrong, I think your solution is very simple and clear, but it is I who do not understand JS, I'm just a fan.

Comment: @EmanueleDaniele it's ok, I understand your choice as I myself was a beginner at JS just a few years ago. Just keep going and one day I guarantee you'll have the same itch I have to solve simple issues with JS (sometimes I even overdo it ;-;).